# previous data of an outboxData array is replaced by current data on push but also it is added on the new index?

Tags: javascript, angular

onSend(userData){

```
 if(this.user){
  this.outboxData.push(userData);
   console.log(this.outboxData);
 }
```

### Heading ##}

Comment: What do you want to know? whats the error?

Comment: `push` appends the data to the array, it doesn't overwrite the existing data.

Comment: Make sure that your question is `clear and understandable` **before** posting

Comment: if you want to overwrite then you no need to use of push you can just assign the this.outboxData=userData

Answer (score 0):

Push use just to add data to n+1 position. It never replace data.

If you can describe your scenario properly we can help you better.

Comment: new data is added on n+1 position but data on nth position is overwritten by new data....

Comment: Your this code is not sufficient. As it look totally correct. can you share more detail about issue.